# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maxLength')

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

I am getting this error while adding the validation using Yup library in reactjs for max function.
For min, regex and other validation it is working fine except maxLength.

```
export let VALIDATION_CONFIG = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('VALIDATION_CONFIG'));

export const Validation = {
    min: (field) => { return Number(VALIDATION_CONFIG[field].minLength) },
    max: (field) => { return Number(VALIDATION_CONFIG[field].maxLength) },
    regex: (field) => { return RegExp(VALIDATION_CONFIG[field].regex) },
    msg: (field) => { return VALIDATION_CONFIG[field].message[SELECTED_LOCALE] },
}
```

**validation.js**

```
name: Yup.string()
        .min(SPSUtils.Validation.min('firstName'), 'Minimum required length is '+SPSUtils.Validation.min('firstName')+' characters.')
        .max(SPSUtils.Validation.max('firstName'), 'Maximum required length is '+SPSUtils.Validation.max('firstName')+' characters.')
        .required('Required.')
        .matches(SPSUtils.Validation.regex('firstName'), {
            message: SPSUtils.Validation.msg('firstName'),
        }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially, VALIDATION_CONFIG is undefined. So you need to insert a question mark. In ES6, it means only if VALIDATION_CONFIG is not undefined, minLength, maxLength .. will be executed.

```
export const Validation = {
    min: (field) => { return Number(VALIDATION_CONFIG[field].minLength) },
    max: (field) => { return Number(VALIDATION_CONFIG[field].maxLength) },
    regex: (field) => { return RegExp(VALIDATION_CONFIG[field].regex) },
    msg: (field) => { return VALIDATION_CONFIG[field].message[SELECTED_LOCALE] },
}
```